# How do I find the max and min of a numeric wrt a factor in data frame in r?

Tags: r, aggregate, sapply

I have a data frame with a few columns and need to calculate the difference between the average of a variable with respect to a factor. For example:

```
C1    C2 
3     A
5     B
9     A
10    A
12    A
9     B
20    B
```

And I want to get:

```
A 9
B 15
```

I tried

```
aggregate(C1 ~ C2, data = df, FUN = function(x) max()-min())
```

but it didn't work. I have the feeling I should use sapply, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined an anonymous function but have not specified what variables to use anywhere.

Replace `function(x) max() - min()` with `function(x) max(x) - min(x)`.

In other words:

```
aggregate(C1 ~ C2, mydf, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
#   C2 C1
# 1  A  9
# 2  B 15
```

You could also conceivably use: `aggregate(C1 ~ C2, mydf, function(x) diff(range(x)))`.